# Selenium python - looping through the tr and check i the td value is not 15 or 16

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to go through every tr and check the 4th td in every tr to check that the value of that td is not 15 or 16

This is how the HTML page looks like [image]

and this is how the html code looks like

[image]

Not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Can you let us have the URL for this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to approximate the content of that page with this. Notice that the rows are the same except that I've made the fourth columns distinct.

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">237229877</td>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">10-1 </td>
        <td class="Data1">Church </td>
        <td class="Data1">Corporation </td>
        <td class="Data1">BELFAST </td>
        <td class="Data1">IRELAND </td>
        <td class="Data1">. </td>
        <td class="Data1">00000-0000 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">03 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">98 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">237229877</td>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">10-2 </td>
        <td class="Data1">Church </td>
        <td class="Data1">Corporation </td>
        <td class="Data1">BELFAST </td>
        <td class="Data1">IRELAND </td>
        <td class="Data1">. </td>
        <td class="Data1">00000-0000 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">03 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">98 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">237229877</td>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">10-3 </td>
        <td class="Data1">Church </td>
        <td class="Data1">Corporation </td>
        <td class="Data1">BELFAST </td>
        <td class="Data1">IRELAND </td>
        <td class="Data1">. </td>
        <td class="Data1">00000-0000 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">03 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">98 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">237229877</td>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">10-4 </td>
        <td class="Data1">Church </td>
        <td class="Data1">Corporation </td>
        <td class="Data1">BELFAST </td>
        <td class="Data1">IRELAND </td>
        <td class="Data1">. </td>
        <td class="Data1">00000-0000 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">03 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">98 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">237229877</td>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">10-5 </td>
        <td class="Data1">Church </td>
        <td class="Data1">Corporation </td>
        <td class="Data1">BELFAST </td>
        <td class="Data1">IRELAND </td>
        <td class="Data1">. </td>
        <td class="Data1">00000-0000 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">03 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">98 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">237229877</td>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">10-6 </td>
        <td class="Data1">Church </td>
        <td class="Data1">Corporation </td>
        <td class="Data1">BELFAST </td>
        <td class="Data1">IRELAND </td>
        <td class="Data1">. </td>
        <td class="Data1">00000-0000 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">03 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">98 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">237229877</td>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">10-7 </td>
        <td class="Data1">Church </td>
        <td class="Data1">Corporation </td>
        <td class="Data1">BELFAST </td>
        <td class="Data1">IRELAND </td>
        <td class="Data1">. </td>
        <td class="Data1">00000-0000 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">03 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">98 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">237229877</td>
        <td class="Data1">1.</td>
        <td class="Data1">10-8 </td>
        <td class="Data1">Church </td>
        <td class="Data1">Corporation </td>
        <td class="Data1">BELFAST </td>
        <td class="Data1">IRELAND </td>
        <td class="Data1">. </td>
        <td class="Data1">00000-0000 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">03 </td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1"></td>
        <td class="Data1">98 </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

You can recover the fourth columns using code like this.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('file://c:/scratch/temp.htm')
>>> row = 1
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         td = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[%s]/td[4]'%row)
...         td.text
...         row+=1
...     except:
...         break
... 
'10-1'
'10-2'
'10-3'
'10-4'
'10-5'
'10-6'
'10-7'
'10-8'
```

Answer (score 2):

Please include the actual HTML code, and not an image of the code.

What you are trying to do can be accomplished by finding the rows, then finding the columns, then checking the 4th column in the array. I can't see the `<table>` element, so you'll have to figure out how to define that yourself.

```
table = driver.find_element_by_whatever-method-you-use(...)
rows = table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    if cols[3].text == '15' or cols[3].text == '16':
        # do whatever
```